# Search nothing for annotation in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij Idea can't search the ComponentScan annotation and other annotations which the spring-framework is newly added to the project, if is it need to update the file index for the Intellij Idea? If so, how to reindex?

[image]

Comment: I restarted the Intellij Idea then it appears, I don' t want to restart every time I add a new maven jar.

Comment: If you add a new maven dependency, you can click on the "Reimport all maven projects" toobar button in the maven toolwindow. You can also select "Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> Import Maven projects automatically"